# SQL Server 2012 : copy a column from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, join, copy, inner-join, where-clause

I have two tables

TABLE1

```
skillid    skillname
1          PM
2          SM
```

TABLE2

```
name skillid skillname
A       1    
B       2
```

I want to get the `skillname` from `table1` while inserting values into `table2`

Comment: What you have tried so far, please share your query?

Comment: This is redundant - you should *not* store the `skillname` in `Table2`, but instead refer to `Table1` if you need to. Relational design is all about *avoiding* redundancies.

Comment: What do you do if someone updates the skillnames in table 1?

Answer (score 2):

Use the below query

```
UPDATE  T2
SET T2.skillname =  T1.skillname
FROM    TABLE2  T2
    INNER JOIN TABLE1 TI ON T1.skillid = T2.skillid
```

Comment: is it possible to do this while insertion itself

Comment: @user3853596 create a sql trigger to capture insert events, inside your trigger add implementation to insert new data to another database table

Comment: Yes, plz share your insert script.

Answer (score 0):

```
 INSERT INTO Table2
 SELECT @Name,
        @skillid,
        skillname
 FROM Table1 T1
 WHERE T1.skillid = @skillid
```

if you are using parameters to insert into table2.

Comment: thank you for your answers i have come up with it works
declare @skilln int
set @skilln=4
insert into  table2 
select 'A',@skilln,s.skillname from table1 s 
where skillid=@skilln